# Autoware - How to train my own pointpillars model?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

- Autoware version : 1.13.0-alpha.1-8-gbebcb65
- ROS Version Melodic
- Autoware installed from source

I am trying to use pointpillars with autoware and I would like to train my own model, because I would like to train a more complete model with other datasets.

First of all it's very hard to find anything on how to train this model, and to make it compatible with autoware. I used this git repo : [SmallMunich/nutonomy_pointpillars](https://github.com/SmallMunich/nutonomy_pointpillars) to train the dataset and convert it to the ONNX file format but it doesn't work. Here is the pointpillars log :  https://pastebin.com/VNMc2EH5

Can you help me reproduce the result with the KITTI dataset first and get ONXX files working ? Thanks a lot !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338179/autoware---how-to-train-my-own-pointpillars-model-?/) by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2019-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-11-21**:
I think right place to search for this is github issues and if you don't find anything then ask for help there.

**Comment by [ryontang](https://answers.ros.org/users/67796/ryontang/) on 2021-01-13**:
hi, Thanks for your share, I also wanna use  SmallMunich/nutonomy_pointpillars to train and gain the ONNX file to locate in Autoware, so have you succeeded in doing that?

**Comment by [ryontang](https://answers.ros.org/users/67796/ryontang/) on 2021-01-13**:
Hi, @Mackou, Maybe we can have some communication on this issue, which is located model in Autoware trained by ourselves.

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2021-01-21**:
Hey @ryontang and sorry for the late reply.
I have managed to train my model using the SmallMunich repo. But I have never been able to output the trained model in a format that autoware could accept.
I know that a team member rewrote the pointpillar node of autoware from scratch so it could accept this model.

**Comment by [ryontang](https://answers.ros.org/users/67796/ryontang/) on 2021-01-25**:
Hi, @Mackou, thanks for your reply. You mean there is a way that need to rewrite the pointpillar node, actually it is a little dificulty for me, all right, keep in touch, if we have made any progress in this problem.

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2021-01-26**:
@ryontang We have totally stopped working on this problem. And unfortunately the new node is proprietary so I cannot share it here.

**Comment by [ryontang](https://answers.ros.org/users/67796/ryontang/) on 2021-02-09**:
@Mackou, All right, sorry for the late reply, and thanks for your share about the problems you have met !!!

**Comment by [ryontang](https://answers.ros.org/users/67796/ryontang/) on 2021-03-19**:
Hi, @Mackou, We have the same error ingormation when load the ONNX file exported by git repo : SmallMunich/nutonomy_pointpillars.
I am sorry, could you give me some advice on rewritting pointpillar node of autoware. so it could accept this model.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used this repo. But it is not well maintained.
Hope this will help.

https://github.com/k0suke-murakami/train_point_pillars

---

Originally posted by [kosuke_murakami](https://answers.ros.org/users/41340/kosuke_murakami/) with karma: 81 on 2019-11-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2019-11-28**:
@kosuke_murakami Thanks for your answer !
How did you convert the model to ONNX ?

**Comment by [ryontang](https://answers.ros.org/users/67796/ryontang/) on 2021-01-13**:
From the issue of this github project https://github.com/k0suke-murakami/tr..., it seems the ONNX file have some mistakes

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi [@kosuke_murakami](https://answers.ros.org/users/41340/kosuke_murakami/) , I am trying to train your repo bu there are some problems. When train using configs/pointpillars/car/xyres_16.config file, code falling the assertion, your comments;

```
assert 10 == len(ret_dict), f"something wrong with training output size!"
```

How can I fix this issues, or could you provide proper config file?

---

Originally posted by [ssfs](https://answers.ros.org/users/40254/ssfs/) with karma: 11 on 2019-12-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1